# sql server ISNULL not working for my query

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

This is my second question about this problem. I would like get sum of column roll_sum
script:

```
($sum_number + (SELECT SUM(roll_sum) FROM table_name))
```

not work  because collumn ROLL_SUM is NULL. But if try use replacement:

```
($sum_number + (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(roll_sum, 0)) FROM table_name))
```

not work aswell. But second script should replace NULL to 0?

Comment: I think your select statement is not returning any row.

Comment: how about ISNULL ( (SELECT SUM(roll_sum) from table_name) ,0)

Comment: `SELECT COALESCE(SUM(roll_sum), 0) FROM table_name`

Comment: @Ullas It is possible insert 0 in to column on first record?

Comment: @user3747585 : Sorry, I didn't unserstand your question.

Comment: @Ullas My script is: ($php_variable + SELECT COALESCE(SUM(roll_sum), 0) FROM table_name). But on first row roll_sum is NULL than coalesce replace to 0 and i have $variable + 0. It is possible insert 0 on first record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap `ISNULL()` with `SUM()`:

```
SELECT isnull(SUM(roll_sum), 0) FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem in your sql query but, you are calling sql query in php statement directly.
The below is sample code. please refer to it.

```
$db = mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("dbname", $db) or die("connection failed");

$query = mysql_query("select sum(roll_sum) as sum from table_name", $db);
$query_row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

// to do something you want
$value = $sum_number + $query_row["sum"];

mysql_close($db);
```